# how pass parameters from hidden fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

please help solve the problem.

from view im send form via POST-method.

show view:

```
.........
........
<%= form_tag(user_change_poll_state_path(@user), method: :post, id: 'state_poll_form') do %> 
  <%= hidden_field(:act, :to_close) %>
  <%= hidden_field(:user_id, @user.id) %>
  <button type="submit" class="" id="statePollSubmit">Закрыть</button>
<% end %>
.........
..............
```

controller:

```
class PollsController < ApplicationController
  def show    
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @images = @poll.images.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  end

  def change_poll_state
    p '000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
    p state_poll_params[:act]
    p state_poll_params[:user_id]

    render 'show'
  end

  private
    def state_poll_params
      params.permit(:act, :user_id)
    end            
end
```

after submit form console displays follow:

```
Started POST "/users/3/change_poll_state" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-27 14:00:13 +0300
Processing by PollsController#change_poll_state as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"H2dFsSe9MDnCC2qLqT+GbltjvqIrC84Nf/h1Hnx5JN4WH/qGCRbIcsJi9kxe9qw+Fk9kHMvkhEkhxVestOnFVQ==", "act"=>{"to_close"=>""}, "user_id"=>"3"}
"000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, act
nil
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, act
"3"
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, act
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

please help pass :act and :user_id values to action 'change_poll_state'

Comment: It would be `params[:act]` `params[:user_id]` on your controller.

Comment: thanks. its really worked. but these parameters is not secure

Answer (score -1):

Try changing

```
<%= hidden_field(:act, :to_close) %>
```

Into

```
<%= hidden_field_tag(:act, :to_close) %>
```

Then in your controller,

```
p state_poll_params[:act]
# => 'to_close'
p state_poll_params[:act].to_sym
# => :to_close
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Forgot the `_tag`. Why would you downvote my answer without even commenting?! Was just trying to help.